# Give focus to an item under tabBar

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

How to give focus to an item under the `tvOS` native `tabBar`?

For example the application `myCanal` do this as shown below:

A swipe down moves the focus from the main tabBar to the second tabBar.

[image]

[image]

How to custom focus engine to get this specific behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Swipe down is moving the focus from the TabBar to the view controller that is presented in the selected tab.

Focusing the second tab bar can be achieved setting the [preferredFocusEnvironmet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocusenvironment/1648972-preferredfocusenvironments) in the view controller that is presented by the tab bar.

Example:

```
final class TheViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet private var theSecondTabBar: UIView!

   override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
       return [theSecondTabBar]
   }
}
```